# Rubber Band (Implement in Unity 2D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rubber

I'm trying to make a rubber band in Unity and I don't get out. I found this example but it's done in Actionscript Flash https://www.deviantart.com/willmh93/art/Ball-Elastic-142211333..... and I can't even convert the code to javaScript or C#. 
I managed to do something similar, but this one uses line renderer, and it's not so real.
[Sling Shot img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Un6G4.png)

My simulation uses the Slingshot mechanism, but it doesn't benefit me. I want to have this rubber band and act on a draggable object. 
I don't need you to write me code, but give me some ideas or some sources from which I can orient myself, what and how to use it to get the same result.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Here's a rope simulator which may be helpful ( https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/physics/obi-rope-55579 ), though looking at the image you may also get away with a much simpler two-lines-and-split-point type of simulation for your needs?

Comment: Yes, but I do not know how successful this asset is ... and if it respects my needs. I need elasticity, specific to a rubber band. As shown in the picture ... if I drag an object, then the rubber band will stretch and if I let it go apply the force on the object.

Comment: But from what I read about the asset, I think it represents my needs. :)

Comment: You could ask the creator of this asset if they think it can cover your use case. Last time I emailed them, they were responsive.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for Spring Joint:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpringJoint.html

It allows you to attach 2 objects with springiness. I'm sure you can fiddle with the values to get a more 'rubber-band' feel.

Comment: Thank you very much ... I tried, and played with all the possible options on the Spring Joint .... and did not give me desired results. )))